# we are reading an ELZ table and sending msg to Kafka. It is a batch job

Tags: apache-kafka, batch-processing

It is a batch job and we are reading an ELZ table and sending message to Kafka.
With current trnsfrmRules if there are 10 rows retrieved from table then 10 messages are sent to Kafka... i.e. One kafka message per Row..
Our requirement is to group the resultSet retrieved from ELZ query based on a column value. Is there any reference for writing transformationRules for such requirement.

Our requirement is to group the resultSet retrieved from ELZ query based on a column value. Is there any reference for writing transformationRules for such requirement.